# Как сделать столбец индексом в обеих таблицах

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение

Есть таблица **df_train** в ней присутсвуют только признаки БЕЗ целевого. По ней нужно обучить модель. Целевой признак находится в другой таблице, она больше, чем **df_train**, т.к это полный датасет **df_full**. Обе таблицы имеют общий стобце `date`.

/Вопрос: Как взять целевой признак по индексу общего столбца `date`.

Comment: что значит _'по индексу общего столбца date'_ ? может по значению из столбца?

Comment: Да, по значению.

Comment: делайте лефтджойн df_train с df_full по столбцу date и берите столбец с целевым признаком

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!